# Yii2 - Create Migration with LONGBLOB field

Tags: mysql, yii2

I want to create a table with a **LONGBLOB** field in it.

```
'image' => $this->binary(),
```

produces **BLOB** field in the table.

Is there any other way to produce **LONGBLOB** field except using raw **SQL** syntax for the specific field.

Below is my full code for creating the table.

```
    $this->createTable('edition_images', [
        'image_id' => $this->bigPrimaryKey()->unsigned(),

        'embed_url' => $this->string()->notNull(),

        'image_type' => $this->string(),
        'image_md5' => $this->string(),
        //'image' => $this->binary(),
        '`image` longblob NULL',

        'title_en' => $this->string(),
        'title_bg' => $this->string(),
        'title_ro' => $this->string(),

        'order' => $this->bigInteger(20)->unsigned()->null(),

        'edition_id' => $this->bigInteger(20)->unsigned()->notNull(),

        'created_by' => $this->bigInteger(20)->unsigned()->notNull(),
        'created_at' => $this->timestamp()->notNull()->defaultExpression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        'updated_by' => $this->bigInteger(20)->unsigned()->null(),
        'updated_at' => $this->timestamp()->null()->defaultValue(null)->append('ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        'deleted_by' => $this->bigInteger(20)->unsigned()->null(),
        'deleted_at' => $this->timestamp()->null(),
        'deleted' => $this->integer(1),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the exact column type as text:

```
'image' => 'LONGBLOB'
```

You should be able to specify the length as a parameter in the [`binary`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait.html#binary()-detail) method. Since the longblob is 4GB you have to specify this in bytes:

```
'image' => $this->binary(4294967295),
```

However, `$length` is being ignored. The code

```
$this->db->createCommand()->createTable("test_blob", [
    "id"    => $this->integer(),
    "datum" => $this->binary(429496729),
    "txt"   => $this->string()
])->getSql();
```

returns the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_blob` (
    `id` int(11),
    `datum` blob,
    `txt` varchar(255)
);
```

I've added an [issue on Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12618)

Comment: I already have tried `'image' => $this->binary(4294967295),` but it produces blob field. I'll try your other suggestion

Comment: Are you on a 32 bit machine by any chance?

Comment: `'image' => 'LONGBLOB',` this works, but i prefer this to work `'image' => $this->binary(4294967295),` . Do you have any suggestions what may be the reason for producing blob field instead of longblob @topher

Comment: `binary()` method is always using the schema-related type regardless of the given length parameter (for MySQL it's `BLOB`).

Comment: So there is no way to produce `longblob` using `$this->...` @Bizley

Comment: I guess something like `$this->db->schema->createColumnSchemaBuilder('longblob')` might work but it's pointless.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I've edited the answer with more info.